# Apple Wallet - What is the distance from a location waypoint when I'll get the notification?

Tags: ios, location, apple-push-notifications, passbook, wallet

Apple Wallet passes has the ability to add up to 10 location way-points to it that will trigger a lock screen notification when the device will be **X** meters from that way-point.

I've been trying to figure out that **X** for a long time but could not find any documentation for it. I know Android Pay are using a default distance of 150 meters but I don't know the answer to Apple Wallet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to find but according to [UrbanAirship](https://www.urbanairship.com/) the radius for some cards is **100 meters** (Loyalty,Gift cards, Coupon, Member cards) while other cards are **1000 meters** (Event,  Boarding pass, Generic).

Full description can be found here:
https://docs.urbanairship.com/reach/reference.html#pass-types